# extract specific numbers and calcula

Tags: pandas, numpy, extract

I have an input -Dimension and I want my output in a specific form extracted from the text that I have in the dimension column.

I have used

```
df['output'] = df['Dimension'].str.extractall(r'(\d*\.?\d+)').astype(float).unstack().prod(axis=1)
```

but i'm not able to print the desired output for Model E. Please help me here in python.

| Model | Dimension | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4.31 m x 2 m x 3.222 m | 27.77364 |
| B | 220m | 220 |
| C | 'St 473m | 473 |
| D | rangeZng 2x250m | 500 |
| E | Original 250ml 2s 35% | 500 |
| F | Qstd 550ml 1+1 | 550 |
| G | very good cream 250ml 2s 35% | 500 |
| H | very good cream 250ml 2s 45% | 500 |

Comment: I have an error as ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape, how to proceed?

Comment: the code fails to print 300 for this text Niv.Shwr F/Blend Apct300m 2sPO
any idea how can this be rectified? @mozway

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe change your regex to:

```
df['output'] = (df['Dimension'].str.extractall(r'(?<![+])(\d*\.?\d+)(?![%+])(?=\D|$)')
                .astype(float).unstack().prod(axis=1)
               )
```

Output:

```
  Model                     Dimension     output
0     A        4.31 m x 2 m x 3.222 m   27.77364
1     B                          220m  220.00000
2     C                      'St 473m  473.00000
3     D               rangeZng 2x250m  500.00000
4     E         Original 250ml 2s 35%  500.00000
5     F                Qstd 550ml 1+1  550.00000
6     G  very good cream 250ml 2s 35%  500.00000
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ymWgUz/1)

Comment: I ran this but it says ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

Comment: @CBCB please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that reproduces the error, the code works well with the current input. Very likely you first need to reset your index: `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: You can also replace `.unstack().prod(axis=1)` by `.groupby(level=0).prod()` (this will aggregate by index, so be careful if you have duplicates!)

Comment: Yes I have many duplicates in my dataset and these are on different columns, how to get the output if I have duplicates? @mozway

Comment: What matters is that your index is not duplicated (run `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my code), but please focus your question on a specific issue. It looks to me that the core problem here (extracting the product of numbers) is solved, no? Also, why don't you provide a reproducible example (output of `df.to_dict('tight')` as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76420393/edit) to your question) to avoid wasting time?